# React Router Link to New Tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to render a new component in a new tab using React Router. It has one parameter that is being passed.

Below is an example of what works for me **in the same tab with one parameter**. If I add target="_blank" to the below link, I get a 404 error.

Routing in index.js:

```
<Route exact path="/a-graph/:anId" component={aGraph} />
```

Link in main menu page:

```
<Link to={"/a-graph/anId"} style={{ overflowX: "visible", color: "black" }}>
    <MenuItem fitted key="graph" text="A Graph"/>
</Link>
```

What do I need to change so that I can open this component with a parameter in a new tab? Thanks!

Edit: my URL is displayed as /a-graph/anId which is a number. If my route and link are correct, I don't see how I'd get a 404. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 5):

```
<Link target="_blank" to={"/a-graph/anId"} style={{ overflowX: "visible", color: "black" }}>
    <MenuItem fitted key="graph" text="A Graph"/>
</Link>
```

As found here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2188#issuecomment-146366561

> In 1.0 this is supported. We just pass all extra props you give your `<Link>`through to the `<a>` element. So, `<Link ... target="_blank">` will work as you'd expect.

Comment: target="_blank" works for me if I don't have a parameter but I get a 404 when I do have a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by 'parameter'?

Comment: In my example, I am referring to the anId value in the path. As I see it, it's an ID value I am passing to the new tab. @TKoL

Comment: Do you have the id at the time of rendering the Link? `<Link to={\`/a-graph/${anId}\`}`

Comment: Yes I do have the ID when the link is rendered. It is set by a user logging in with the page containing the link then being rendered.

Thank you so much for responding back! @TKoL